# How to use Custom Authorizer on Api Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

**Custom Authorization** 
**Lambda Execution Role :** Full Access Api Gateway and Lambda 
**Token Source:** method.request.header.Authorization 
**Token Validation:** blank

Add this custom authorization to api method request . Authorizers test is succes but ı request to api on Postman then 401.

```
{
    "message": "Unauthorized"
}
```

[image: Authorizers Test Image] 
[image: Postman Image] 
[image: Api Method Request Image]

**Custom Authorizer Lambda**

```
console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    
    console.log("event:",JSON.stringify(event));    console.log("event:",JSON.stringify(context));
    console.log('Client token: ' + event.authorizationToken);
    console.log('Method ARN: ' + event.methodArn);
callback(null, {
    "principalId": "18",
    "policyDocument": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "Stmt1459758003000",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "execute-api:Invoke"
                ],
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:execute-api:*"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});

}
```

**Postman Code:**

```
    curl --request GET \
  --url {url} \
  --header 'authorization: Test Token' \
  --header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --header 'postman-token: c9110a92-414e-e1aa-61fb-194758dace86'
```

**Solution**
**Token Source:** Authorization

Answer (score 1):

API Gateway has changed, as of today Jan 18. Following needs to be know.

1. If the Method's Integration Request is not lambda proxied. While creating custom authorier (in Authorizer tab) , you should enter Token Source as  "Authorization" and not "method.request.header.Authorization". Also , in the Method Request tab of the method ( eg GET) , you should set the HTTP Header Mapping , for 'Authorization'.
2. If the Method's Integration Request is proxied , no mapping is required. All the request body+header+parameter+AWSextraStuff is avaliable in the event[] object of lambda. Hence no mapping is required.

Few more pitfall be careful. 
- Use standard string like 'Authorization' ( which is a standard) , is you use different string , change every where.
- The authorization token when passed to lambda, for no proxied integration request, as event['authorizationToken']and not event['Authorization']
- If you get error like Lambda Malform... , it is because you are using Lambda Proxy and it requires response in specific format, your not sending data in tha format.
- If your using Postman , switch to 'raw' against 'pretty' mode.

Comment: I am using proxy Integration with custom authorization and I want my Authorization to come under in my event object. What additional settings, I have to do then and I have already set custom authorization configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

To call an API with the custom TOKEN authorizer

- Open Postman, choose the GET method and paste the API's Invoke URL into the adjacent URL field.

Add the custom authorization token header and set the value to allow. Choose Send.

[image]

Worth read - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html#call-api-with-api-gateway-custom-authorization

Comment: Thanks for answer :) ı solved it problem is  Token Source: method.request.header.Authorization . it is must be Token Source: Authorization

Comment: Excellent man :). Is that the same answer I have shared helped?

Answer (score 0):

You don't call the Custom Authorizer through Postman, that's API Gateways' job.

Every time that you call an endpoint protected by your custom authorizer the API Gateway will check if the value of the given Authorization Header exists in its Policies Cache. If the value does not exist, your Custom Authorizer will be called to authenticate the request.

A simple representation of the flow:

```
Lambda Handler (handles a protected endpoint GET /users/{id})
    |
    | ------------ 
    |            |
    |     Custom Authorizer
    |          /
    |         / (if the request is not authorized yet)
    |        /
 Api Gateway 
    |
    |
    |
Request (with Authorization Header)
```

You just have to set the Authorization of your resource method to your custom authorizer and let the API Gateway do all the work.

Comment: Thanks for answer :) ı solved it problem is  Token Source: method.request.header.Authorization . it is must be Token Source: Authorization

Comment: Why can't you add your answer in the answer session? So that it would be helpful for others as well. I have already seen somebody else asked the same question you asked. I have given the answer but if you add it the answer session then I can share yours as the answer and reputation comes to you. I don't want the credit as this is your solution :)

Comment: I would add. I did not understand the credit thing. In the meantime, I've added a solution to the problem:)

Comment: When you answer it in the community you will get reputation :).